# search for partial folder name and return dir to use with batch

Tags: batch-file, search, directory, find, filepath

Firstly i am still a beginner at scripting so please be gentle. 
I am creating a back up script and I want to be able to search network for part of a file name (which located on a networked External HDD for Backup use), then return the dir to use later to back up the contents of a USB device.
The folder name I am searching for consists of 4 elements as follows: Date-1234567-Type-User.
The part i am looking to search for is the 7 digit id number which is unique where as the other elements may be duplicated a number of times.
the current script i have been using is not returning anything it is giving file not found, could someone point me in the right direction my script is as follows, also i am working on windows 7.

```
@echo off
:start

set /p path=enter id no.:
for /r %%# in (.) do (
       Echo %%~nx# | find "string" "%path%" 1>NUL && (
               Echo Full Path: %%~nx#
               Echo Filename : %%~nx#
               Echo Directory: %%~p#
       )
)

if defined p (
echo %p%
) else ( Echo file not found
)
pause
goto backup

:backup
if not exist "%p%"\"usb download" md "%p%"\"usb download"

if exist (
xcopy /y "USB" "%p%"\usb download
)

pause
goto start
```

the Xcopy lines work on their own creating a new folder and copying the contents however i have to write the complete file path manually which is quite extensive and laborious so if i could automate this it would help dramatically.
I thank you for your help in advance, I have googled and searched my heart out, but as I said I am a beginner and my brain is melting.
thanks all.

Comment: Are you trying to access the `for` variable `%%p` outside of the loop? this is not possible; you need to assign it to an standard variable like `set "VAR=%%~p"` and use `%VAR%` for the remaining code... and you need to put `""` around the whole paths, not around each directory, like `"%VAR%\usb download"` instead of `"%VAR%"\"usb download"`...

Comment: Where variable `p` comes from? Used in `if defined p` and in `echo %p%` etc. but I can't find anything like `set p=%%~p#`. BTW, do not change variable `path`, it has its own [special meaning](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html)

Comment: Don't use path as a variable. It's used by windows to find programs. You break your cmd prompt while it's open.

Comment: so i have used "Var" instead of "path"  where should i set the variable?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to return the full file path of a file containing a variable within a network drive.

i.e Trying to return the file path for a file called "01012001-1234567-TEST-DAVE"
The user definable variable i want to search for is "1234567"
And I want to locate it from the network location "\\NAS-DRIVE\Public\Backup Area"

What I have done above was me playing with code i found from various google searches...   i'm not going to lie.  I only understand some of the code.

I'm really struggling with this...    Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /ad /b /s z:\*1234567*') do echo %A
```

This should find it.

Comment: this worked after i used an extra `%` as follows
    `for /f "delims=" %%A in ect...`